# Java 1.7 HashMap Integer Key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, integer, key

I'm using an `HashMap<Integer, MyObject>` collection to store a list of few couples of values.

Is it safe use Integer as key? the behavior is the same both on put and get method?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: if I put value directly with Integer or by integer.intValue is the same?

Comment: For most purposes.

Comment: If your concern is `Integer` vs `int` then don't worry about it. Apart from `null` either form can be used due to auto-boxing. However, auto-boxing does have performance draw-backs.

Comment: Dear Down-Voters: How is this Question unclear? Seems quite simple and direct to me.

Comment: Your question didn't get down-votes but close-votes. It is reasonable because it is unclear why you think `Integer` would be *unsafe* here. `Map#put(K key, V value)` expect key of type described by generics, in your case `Ineger`. Since generics work only with objects (you can't set it to primitive type like `int`) passed argument of primitive type `int` will be automatically boxed (wrapped/promoted) to Integer, because that is the type expected by methods for this argument. We don't know what you don't know, so you need to explain what makes you think this could be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's safe. `Integer` is just a wrapper class for `int`.
i know this from own experience. created a captcha functionality that way. (user requests a random integer. my prog creates a captcha-pic and saves the answer[value] and random integer id[key] in a hashmap. btw if you want to create a "cache" use java's `LinkedHashMap`. it has a protected boolean method called "`removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest)`" which is called during a put-event. if you override it with, eg "`return size() > MAX_SIZE;`" it will delete the oldest entry (or the entry based on oldest access - there's an option in the constructor) if the condition you provided returns `true`). hope this helped. :/